# Neo4j - Inappropriate Match counts

Tags: neo4j, cypher, query-performance

I am doing some x operation in two different ways. But in the second method, the count of Match query is inappropriate which is no way acceptable. Please suggest where I am missing.

**First Way:**

```
profile
WITH [1234] AS sellers_list,
[12345] AS buyers_list

MATCH (buyer:Person) WHERE buyer.person_guid IN buyers_list
MATCH (seller:Person) WHERE seller.person_guid IN sellers_list

RETURN count(buyer),size(buyers_list),count(seller),size(sellers_list)
```

This results:
[image]

**Second Way**

```
profile
WITH [1234] AS sellers_list,
[12345] AS buyers_list

MATCH (seller_member:Person)-[r:TEAM_MEMBER]-(seller_teammate:Person) 
    WHERE seller_member.person_guid IN sellers_list

WITH FILTER(x IN COLLECT(seller_teammate.person_guid) WHERE NOT(x in sellers_list)) AS sellerteam, sellers_list, buyers_list

MATCH (seller_member:Person)-[r:EMPLOYED_BY]->(b:Organization)
MATCH (b)<-[s:EMPLOYED_BY]-(org_member:Person) 
    WHERE seller_member.person_guid=sellers[0]

WITH FILTER(x IN COLLECT(org_member.person_guid) WHERE NOT(x IN sellerteam)) AS org_members,sellers_list,sellerteam,buyers_list 

WITH sellers+sellerteam+org_members AS all_org_members,sellers_list,sellerteam,org_members,buyers_list


MATCH (buyer:Person) WHERE buyer.person_guid IN buyers_list
MATCH (seller:Person) WHERE seller.person_guid IN all_org_members

RETURN count(buyer),size(buyers_list),count(seller),size(sellers_list)
```

This Results in: 
[image]

In the second method, I did not alter the buyers_list anywhere, I was just count the seller team members and seller organization members that's it. But the count of buyers is changing. Why?

Profiling the above query shows this:
[image]

Looking at this image, the no of buyers is just 1, but why the count is returning 45k.

And, why the 90k db hits for 45k nodes? Any specific reason and how can I reduce the db hits here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key thing to remember is that queries in Neo4j build up rows and columns. When you perform a match between disconnected patterns, you tend to get a cartesian product against your current rows (and you can see that in your query plan). That said, a cartesian product isn't necessarily a mistake or bad. There's really no way to match to all those sellers from your list of guids without a cartesian product, and it is just a cartesian product against your single row.

If you returned all values immediately after your seller match, you would see that each row has a different seller, but all the other fields (including the buyer) are the same.

You'll want to get a count of distinct values, `count(distinct buyer)`, which should give you your expected buyer count of 1.

As for the 90k hits, a NodeUniqueIndexSeek requires 2 db hits per lookup, and you performed a lookup on 45k values, so the math works out.

EDIT

If you are still suspicious, you can try out a large unique lookup in isolation (or as much isolation as you can while having to lookup 45k guids first).

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WITH p LIMIT 45000
WITH COLLECT(p.person_guid) as guids
// you can always take the above subquery, returning 1, to see the timing of just collecting guids
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.person_guid in guids
RETURN COUNT(p) as count
```

Comment: Is there any other way we can reduce the dbhits to optimise the query?

Comment: One unique lookup is 2 db hits. The only way to reduce the db hits is to reduce the number of lookups you're performing. That said, unique lookups tend to be pretty quick, those usually aren't the sources of performance problems. You're doing some pretty heavy collection operations and combining. Those can be problematic sometimes, I'd look at those first.

Comment: I added a suggestion for checking timing for both collecting properties of nodes, and matching to nodes from guids. By the way, is there some reason why you're working with guids rather than the nodes themselves? Property access can be expensive, and you'd be able to skip your match from guids to nodes.

Comment: Agree, I am trying out with nodes instead of properties. There is no specific reason for collecting guids.